# Why can't I use align="" in a css file?

Tags: css

Just curious: 
I have a very simple webpage. I am toying with css files to make it look different.

Especially various divs:

```
 <div align="center">
```

Apparently, this align="center" cannot, should not, be put in the css file.

I can set the width, background, text style etc.

Why is align not allowed in css?

Comment: Because it's deprecated) You can use `text-align: center;` instead. Or `flex-align: center;`

Comment: or use flex-box, if you want to align more than text

Comment: You could also ask why you can't use `<center>`

Comment: It doesn't seem to respond to flex-align: center; I use Bluefish as my editor. It does not highlight flex-align: center; But width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; does put the div in the middle of the screen. What I'm trying, in my amateur way, is to make the page display better on a mobile. So I thought, centre things and set a small width. Most students where I am don't possess a laptop!

Answer (score 2):

Because `align=` is an HTML attribute (an old one) and doesn't have anything to do with CSS.

CSS properties for centering things are different based on the `display` property of the element being centered.

`display: block` elements are centered using a left and right `margin` set to `auto`. Note that a width must be supplied or it won’t work.

`display: inline-block` elements are centered by having the element’s parent set to `text-align: center` (which will center all `inline` and `inline-block` children).

```css
/* block level element */

.aaa {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* this centers with width */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa"></div>
```

and

```css
/* inline-block or inline elements */

.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h3>I’m a title that’s centered</h3>
</div>
```

There is also flexbox, but given the nature of your question it’s probably too confusing for you right now.

Comment: I can put width: 800px; directly in the div. Is that not an html attribute? I have width: 800px and margin: 0 auto; in the css file now, but before they were in each div.

Comment: There's a lot of things you "can" do in html, for backwards compatibility reasons, that probably should have never existed but did and therefore browsers have to continue supporting them else breaking a whole lot of old websites.

Comment: @Pedroski the ONLY attribute having to do with CSS is `style=""`. Inside the `style` attribute you can place any valid css. Such as: `<div style="width: 300px;"></div>`. ANY OTHER attribute is not recommended to style things. I think youre confused because back before there was css many years ago, people used attributes to style things... like this `<div color="#fff" width="500"></div>`. This method is no longer used, but still works in order for backwards compatibility. This is highly NOT recommended, even though yes it works. You should really only be using a CSS file, and style attribute

Comment: Try to avoid using a `style=""` attribute unless absolutely necessary, as inline-styles can make code hard to read (because they have priority over a stylesheet). The best, cleanest approach is to put ALL styles in a CSS file, and no styling as attributes or inline styles (with `style=""`)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can align something by placing it inside a div. Then you have to use "text-align" in CSS. Here's an example

```
<html>
<div id="center">
<p>I'm in the center</p>
</div>
<style>
#center{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</html>
```

That's all you have to do! (hope this helped)